# Problemas de Consulta SQL

Tags: sql-server, select

Tengo dos tablas asociadas llamadas CPV_Personal y CPV_PersonalDocumentos . En la tabla CPV_PersonalDocumentos están registrados todos los documentos con fecha de vencimiento del CPV-Personal

El CPV_Personal puede tener 1, 2 o 3 documentos asociados, "SI UNO" de esos documentos tiene la fecha de vencimiento menor a la fecha actual deberá mostrar un mensaje de "No Ingresa" , y si la fecha de vencimiento es mayor a la fecha actual mostrará un mensaje que "Ingresa"

[image: Tabla CPV_PersonalDocumentos]

El resultado esperado es como sigue, me falta la última columna en base a la condición descrita en la primera parte

[image: Resultado Esperado]

[image: CÓDIGO SQL]

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE usp_PersonalIngreso
(@Ape_Per varchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT distinct
            CPV_PersonalExterno.Id_Per,
            CPV_Empresa.Ras_Emp,
            CONCAT(CPV_PersonalExterno.Ape_Per,' ',CPV_PersonalExterno.Nom_Per) as Apellidos_Nombre, 
            Dni_Per,
            CPV_TipoPersonal.Des_Tip,
            Pue_Per,            
            CASE 
            --ACÁ COMO PODRÍA HACER LA CONDICIÓN, RECORDAR QUE EL PERSONAL PUEDE TENER HASTA 3 DOCUMENTOS
                Y SI UNO DE ELLOS ESTA CON LA FECHA DE VENCIMIENTO CADUCADA MOSTRARÁ UN MENSAJE DE "NO INGRESA"

                WHEN CPV_TipoPersonal.Des_Tip = 'Contratista' AND....
                then 'Ingresa' 

            end as Condicion

    FROM CPV_PersonalExterno 
    INNER JOIN CPV_Empresa ON CPV_PersonalExterno.Id_Emp = CPV_Empresa.Id_Emp
    INNER JOIN CPV_TipoPersonal ON CPV_PersonalExterno.Id_Tip = CPV_TipoPersonal.Id_Tip
    INNER JOIN CPV_PersonalDocumento on CPV_PersonalDocumento.Id_Per != 0
    WHERE Ape_Per like @Ape_Per +'%'
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no mal entendí lo que preguntas, tu requerimiento fundamental es determinar si alguno de los documentos relacionados a cualquier persona de `CPV_PersonalExterno` tiene `Fev_Dop` inferior a la del día, es decir que al menos uno de estos documentos este vencido. La consulta básica para determinar esto podría ser la siguiente:

```
SELECT P.Id_Per,
       CASE WHEN MIN(PD.Fev_Dop) < GETDATE() THEN 'No Ingresa' ELSE 'Ingresa' END
       FROM CPV_PersonalExterno P
       INNER JOIN CPV_PersonalDocumento PD
          ON PD.Id_Per = P.Id_Per
       GROUP BY P.Id_Per
```

Básicamente por cada persona, obtenemos la fecha más antigua y comparamos la misma con la fecha del día, en función de esto retornamos los valores que pides. Esto puede fácilmente incorporarse como subconsulta a la consulta que ya tienes.

Comment: Excelente, gracias doc!